# RELEASE DEBUG in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I was trying to set up two different type of code for my project.When I try to run the following code nothing is printed.I am using cmake and mingw.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**) {
#if DEBUG
std::cout<<"Hello from debug"<<std::endl;
#endif
#if RELEASE
std::cout<< "Hello from release"<<std::endl;
#endif
}
```

Comment: Use `NDEBUG` so `#ifndef NDEBUG`

Comment: Thanks.This worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `NDEBUG`, since it's standardized. It's defined for non-debug -- while normally used with `assert`, I've used it for other things too.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
#ifndef NDEBUG
    std::cout << "Hello from debug" << std::endl;
#else
    std::cout << "Hello from release" << std::endl;
#endif
}
```